# My while loop keeps on sending the last record to my modal

Tags: php

Im trying to send the name of the the record into my modal and echo the `name` and its `id` but i keep on fetching the last record only.

Here are my codes:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Full Name</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Crew Rank</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($stmt)) {
            $full_name = $row['full_name'];
            $idd = $row['id'];
            $crew_rank_table = $row['crew_rank_table'];
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='$idd'>";
                echo "<td onclick='window.open('view_all_info.php?id=$idd', '_blank', 'resizable=no,fullscreen=yes,top=0,left=0,width=1265,height=600')'>".sprintf("%s", $row['full_name'])."</td>";
                echo "<td onclick='window.open('view_all_info.php?id=$idd', '_blank', 'resizable=no,fullscreen=yes,top=0,left=0,width=1265,height=600')'>'.sprintf("%s", $row['crew_status'])."</td>";
                echo "<td onclick='window.open('view_all_info.php?id=$idd', '_blank', 'resizable=no,fullscreen=yes,top=0,left=0,width=1265,height=600')'>".sprintf("%s", $row['crew_rank_table'])."</td>";
                echo "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' href='#myModal' data-toggle='modal'>Send</button></td>";
            echo '</tr>';
         }
      ?>     
</table>
<?php include('modal_send.php'); ?>
```

Here is my code to my modal:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Send Crew to Principal</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="pending_lineup.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">                          
            <div class="control-group">
                <?php
                    echo $idd;
                    echo $full_name;
                ?>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="icon-remove icon-large"></i> Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-info" name="change" type="submit"><i class="icon-save icon-large"></i> Send</button>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
<!-- end  Modal -->
```

I have three data in my table example:

Food
Book
Sleep

and when i click the button beside the food, the data will in my modal is Sleep.

I hope someone will help me. Thank you

Comment: You should really avoid using mysql_ functions they're now deprecated.. Look into using PDO instead would be my advice.

Comment: This is not duplicate

Comment: It is really. It's because his while loop doesn't generate a new modal for each / modify the existing modal.

Comment: how come my question is duplicate to that question?